# Why does the gzip version of files produce a different md5 checksum

Tags: gzip, hashsum

I have four files that I created using an `svndump`

```
test.svn 
test2.svn 
test.svn.gz  
test2.svn.gz
```

now when I run this

```
md5sum test2.svn test.svn test.svn.gz test2.svn.gz
```

Here is the output

```
89fc1d097345b0255825286d9b4d64c3  test2.svn
89fc1d097345b0255825286d9b4d64c3  test.svn
8284ebb8b4f860fbb3e03e63168b9c9e  test.svn.gz
ab9411efcb74a466ea8e6faea5c0af9d  test2.svn.gz
```

So I can't understand why `gzip` is compressing files differently is it putting a timestamp somewhere before compressing? *I had a similar issue with `mysqldump` as it was using the date field on top*

Comment: Dammit I just figured it out, but il let some one rack the points. Of you go answer :D

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`gzip` stores some of the original file's metadata in record header, including the file modification time and filename, if available. See [GZIP file format specification](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#file-format).

So it's expected that your two `gzip` files aren't identical. You can work around this by passing `gzip` the `-n` flag, which stops it from including the original filename and timestamp in the header.

Answer (score 4):

Every .gz file has an header with a name of file... Try `head test.svn.gz` and `head test2.svn.gz`

Comment: That outputs a whole lot of garbage. i don't thing head would work well on test.svn.gz

Comment: In the begining you can see a name of file...

Comment: > head test2.svn.gz 
�����F�u���;��@�� h��'N`�V�D�?Fo�

Comment: `head test2.svn.gz|hexdump -C` won't mess up your terminal

Comment: ohhh nice @Mat love learning new commands